# In Google data studio I have input box filter and I want to have a self join using data blend

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to select all records with value X from the table (This is first table in self join (blend)). I would like to select all email IDs who has used value X sometime but not used other times. In GOogle Data studio with self join, I get required results.

Now I want to generalized the solution by passing value X through input Box. When I apply this using data blend using self join, it selects only values X records as both tables applies filter to input box value.

I have created duplicate table and tried as second table in data blend but the same results.

Solution to this proble is highly appreciated.

- Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the solution.

1. If you are not using parameter, you can use self join to get the required details.
2. If you are using parameter, while using self join filter for the parameter will get automatically updated. But we need all records of email ID in the table and hence results are not correct.
3. The best solution is to create another  table  with the  fields and change the  name  of a field you want to use it for parameter and apply join of these  two tables rather  than using self join.  You will get  required result.